# jquery for loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

i have a below function through which i am trying to append something. it internally calls another function which does the append function..

```
function something()
    for(var i=0; i <= obj.result.length; i++) {
```

**EDIT**

```
    obj = objEval.result[i].uniquename;
    prop = objEval.result[i].prop;
    count = objEval.result[i].count;


        // count is 21 in my case. below function is called..
        if (count > 0){
            callAdd(obj,prop);
        }

    }
}
```

actual function that does the appending

```
function callAdd(obj,prop){
    // obj exists in DOM.. checked via $(obj).length -- greater than 0
    $(obj).append(prop);
}
```

issue here is, even if the append function is in for loop.. only the first element is being sent to the callAdd function.. as below:

i have 4 obj, props:

```
obj=45183371 and prop=6
obj=560488951 and prop=12
obj=616516330 and prop=23
obj=915329019 and prop=5
```

but only the first pair (obj=45183371 and prop=6) is being sent to the callAdd function as params..

pls help..

Comment: What's the point of having an iterator `i` if you're not using it? Don't you need to use something along the lines of `obj[i]` somewhere?

Comment: What needs checking is whether you are passing the same obj and prop every time to the `callAdd` function. Can you paste the exact code which does the calling (and the param passing). Its difficult to tell with just this much code.

Comment: Is count a global variable? I would assume so due to your comment that count is 21 in this case. Have you thought of using the JQuery function .each() instead of doing your own for loop?

Comment: @Peter: I believe i am trying to **//do something** inside the loop.. of course it has something to do!

Comment: @techfoobar : no, everytime in the loop, the obj, prop pair changes.. as shown in the console values.. but when being passed to the function, only first pair is getting passed :(

Comment: @JonVD : how do i use it in this case.. i want to loop thro obj.result[0] and get values in it.. its a json obj..

Comment: Looks like you should have an array of "obj"s and should be iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `count` defined so use `i`:

```
if (i > 0){
    callAdd(obj,prop);
};
```

Comment: We need to see the "do something" part of the function

Comment: obj = objEval.result[i].uniquename;
  prop = objEval.result[i].likes;

Answer (score 0):

something() generally needs to be added a param, other-wise how would it function?  where would it build its loop? Global var? I dont see one

Comment: something has 2 params.. its actually something(param1, param2)

Comment: Yeah but you didnt show that in your code, people cant just guess what your params are going to be...write your full code to get a better effect/response

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Get all objs in an Array.

```
var objAry=new Array();
```

Get all props in an Array.

```
var propsAry=new Array();
```

Now

```
    function something()
    {
        var propsAry=new Array();
        var objAry=new Array();

        objAry= //Your objs
        propsAry=//Your props

        for(var i=0; i <= objAry. length; i++)
        {

            if (count > 0)
            {
                callAdd(objAry[i], propsAry[i]);
            }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the variable you're depending on (`obj`) to limit your loop control variable (`i`). When you re-assign `obj` inside the body of the loop:

```
obj = objEval.result[i].uniquename;
```

The looping condition:

```
i <= obj.result.length
```

Will be false on the next iteration. Inside the body of the loop, create a new variable instead of assigning something new to `obj`.

Alternatively (or additionally), cache the number of iterations you want in a variable instead:

```
var len = obj.result.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
    // Do whatever you want to obj.
}
```